# PDO with json_encode return data as arrays

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having an issue with trying to return my data as 2 dimensional arrays rather than objects in a single array.

I fetch my query results like this:

```
    if($stmt->rowCount()){
        echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); exit;  
    }
```

The data I get from the json_encode is like this:

```
   [
      {"id":"1","name":"Test"},{"id":"2","name":"Test 2"}
   ]
```

How ever i am looking to get the data returned in this format:

```
[0] 
  [0] = "1";
  [1] = "Test";
[1]
  [0] = "2";
  [1] = "Test 2";
```

Does PDO provide such a format when fetching results?

Comment: FWIW, I advise against returning database data directly as it often makes the service API too brittle.

Comment: @user2864740 care to elaborate what you mean by brittle?

Comment: @Dave It provides no isolation between the separate tiers of an application. Changes to the database schema can directly affect the returned value. By defining a clear interface (separate from the schema) at the appropriate boundaries (e.g. Web API), changes can be mitigated/isolated and the entire solution is "less brittle".

Comment: Not sure i even understand what that means :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));` to `echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM));`

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php