# jqGrid: Converting from mysql to PDO - Grid not displaying data

Tags: mysql, pdo, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid and I would like to convert from mysql statements to PDO (PHP Data Objects) but when I convert the statements to PDO the data doesn't display in the grid but I know that the scripts are retrieving data. I looked at the [trirand](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) demos (click on 'Loading Data' then JSON data) and it gives examples with the **deprecated mysql statements**. I am unable to find a lot of resources that aid in the conversion from mysql to PDO for jqGrid.

So the next thing I did was compare the FORMAT of the two sets of outputted data (mysql and PDO).

Here is the mysql formatted data (Output):

```
{"rows":[["01","3701","37010100","37010102","37A","01","Executive Offices","SEC","Office of the Secretary","Y"], etc...]}
```

Then the PDO formatted data (Output):

```
[{"unit_id":"01","div_id":"3701","org_code":"37010100","l1l2_id":"37010102","CSA_id":"37A","area_id":"01","long_desc":"Executive Offices","short_desc":"SEC","unit_desc":"Office of the Secretary","avail_ind":"Y"}]
```

I think that the reason why jqGrid is not display the data in the grid is because it's not accepting the `PDO format` of the data. But I don't know how to format the PDO data to simulate the format that the mysql format. What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749511/pdo-with-json-encode-return-data-as-arrays) and it suggested changing `echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));` to `echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM));` and it formatted the data correctly so jqGrid could display the data.